# Minimal point of the intersection of convex sets. 

Tags: convex-optimization, convex-analysis

I am trying to find out if there is any known result in convex optimization that implies the following statement:
"A minimal point of the intersection of $N > 2$ convex sets in $\mathbb{R}^2$   is a minimal point of the intersection of $2$ sets among the aforementioned $N$."
and more generally:
"A minimal point of the intersection of $N >d$ convex sets in $\mathbb{R}^d$  is a minimal point of the intersection of $d$ sets among the aforementioned $N$."
Note: Minimal point is considered here to be a point in the set that attains the lowest value in one of the Euclidean space dimensions.

Comment: I don't understand your "Note"--it makes no sense to me.

Comment: I'd like to dwell on your question, but I need a complete, precise definition of "minimal point", as you use it.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be an immediate consequence of Helly's theorem, applied to the given convex sets  and the set of points where the space-dimension in the "Note" is smaller than its minimum over the intersection.